Capturing event responses with Microsoft Exchange API
I have a legacy program that I need to add to. What it does is scan a db table every set interval and creates Outlook invitations based on information from the table. This program uses the C# Microsoft Exchange API and I need to add a feature. What I need to do is take responses to events by users and create new db entries to log them. I don't want to scan the inbox that created the events because not all users will respond with an email and I don't want to scan all events from the db because there are thousands added per day and that will take too long.
Can anyone help me find a way to retrieve users' responses as they happen so I can update the table dynamically when people respond to invitations?
I tried scanning all appointments but that is too costly

        /// <summary>
        /// Get all appointments that haven't occured yet and check invitee status
        /// </summary>
        private static void checkInviteeStatusAllAppointments()
        {
            //ENTER ELON QUERY TO SELECT RELEVANT APPOINTMENT IDs
            List<int> appointmentIDs = new List<int>();
            int numAppointments = appointmentIDs.Count;
            writeToLog($"found {} appointment IDs", MESSAGE);
            //---------------

            //DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TABLE_END_DATE);
            //DateTime now = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now);
            //string selectQuery = $"select * from {TABLE_NAME} where {TABLE_END_DATE} <> {now}";
            //writeToLog($"query: {selectQuery}", MESSAGE);

            //m_TableRows = mSqlConnect.GetFromDB(selectQuery);
            //writeToLog($"found {m_TableRows.Count} rows", MESSAGE);

            if (m_TableRows.Count > 0)
            {
                initExchangeService();
                writeToLog("----------------------------------------------", MESSAGE);

                // Iterating rows
                foreach (var row in m_TableRows)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string appointmentType = row[TABLE_TYPE];
                        writeToLog($"working on new line with {TABLE_ID} {row[TABLE_ID]}, type: {appointmentType}", MESSAGE);

                        switch (appointmentType.ToUpper())
                        {
                            case INSERT_APPOINTMENT_LETTER:
                                createAppointment(row);
                                break;
                            case UPDATE_APPOINTMENT_LETTER:
                                updateAppointment(row);
                                break;
                            case CANCEL_APPOINTMENT_LETTER:
                                deleteAppointment(row);
                                break;
                            default:
                                updateTableOnError(row[TABLE_ID], "Not a valid type");
                                throw new Exception("Not a valid type");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        writeToLog(ex.Message, ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        writeToLog("----------------------------------------------", MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Captures the responses of invitees for an appointment given the row denoting it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="row">The row representing the appointment</param>
        private static void CaptureInviteeResponses(Dictionary<string, string> row)
        {
            string appointmentId = row[TABLE_APPOINTMENT_ID];
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appointmentId))
                {
                    throw new Exception(message: $"Error. No ID for row {row}.");
                }

                Appointment appointment = Appointment.Bind(m_ExchangeService, appointmentId);

                writeToLog($"Successfully bound to appointment with ID: {appointmentId}", MESSAGE);

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(logAttendeeResponses), appointment);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                writeToLog($"Error capturing responses for appointment ID {appointmentId}: {ex.Message}", ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Iterate all invitees of an appointment and log their responses to the invitation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="i_appointment">The appointment to be examined</param>
        private static void logAttendeeResponses(object i_appointment)
        {
            Appointment appointment = (Appointment)i_appointment;

            // Retrieve the responses of required attendees
            foreach (Attendee attendee in appointment.RequiredAttendees)
            {
                string response = attendee.ResponseType == MeetingResponseType.NoResponseReceived ? "No response received" : attendee.ResponseType.ToString();
                writeToLog($"Required Attendee: {attendee.Address}, Response: {response}", MESSAGE);
            }

            // Retrieve the responses of optional attendees
            foreach (Attendee attendee in appointment.OptionalAttendees)
            {
                string response = attendee.ResponseType == MeetingResponseType.NoResponseReceived ? "No response received" : attendee.ResponseType.ToString();
                writeToLog($"Optional Attendee: {attendee.Address}, Response: {response}", MESSAGE);
            }
        }



